# hadoop pig joining on any matching tuple values

Tags: arrays, join, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm new to pig and trying to use it to process a dataset. I have a set of records that looks like

```
id    elements
--------------
1     ["a","b","c"]
2     ["a","f","g"]
3     ["f","g","h"]
```

The idea is that I want to create tuples of elements that have any overlapping elements. If elements was just a single item instead of array, I could do a simple join like:

```
A = LOAD 'mydata' ...
B = FOREACH A GENERATE id as id_2, elements as elements_2;
C = JOIN A BY elements, B BY elements_2;
```

But since `elements` is an array, this won't work if there is only a partial overlap. Any thoughts on how to do this in pig?

The intended output would give the tuples that have overlap:

```
(1,2)
(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use `JOIN` for this.
One (not so elegant) solution is to `CROSS` both relations and then do a `FILTER` operation.
The `FILTER` condition could either be a UDF or some kind of regex_extract_all and a matching of the produced fields. If the size of the array is always 3 I would probably go for the regex_extract_all solution.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I was able to do it differently by splitting each element into its own line and then using join and group.