# hadoop pig self join performance

Tags: join, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a dataset of users and elements in which I would like to find any pairs of users that have at least one overlapping element. My data structure looks like:

```
id    element
--------------
1     a    
1     b
1     b
2     b
3     a
4     c
```

In this case, I would generate the following tuples:

```
(1,2) // both have element "b" in common
(1,3) // both have element "a" in common
```

I've written the following pig script that works at small scales, but when I even 1 million rows (~500MB), I killed the job after 1.5 hours because it had generated nearly 40GB of data, which seems a little out of proportion for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm new to pig, so I'm hoping this can be optimized a bit. Any help would be appreciated.

```
-- load the data
mydata = LOAD '/path/to/my/data' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (user:int, element:chararray);
-- generate a copy to do a self join with
A = FOREACH mydata GENERATE user as user_2, element as element_2;
-- join them based on common tags
B = JOIN mydata BY element, A by element_2;
-- we only want the mapping in one direction, e.g. (1,2) is the same as (2,1)
C = FILTER B BY user < user_2;
-- we're only interested in the user ids
D = FOREACH C generate user, user_2;
-- remove any duplicate tuples
E = DISTINCT D;
STORE E INTO '/path/to/output';
```

Note: This is a follow-up to my previous question [hadoop pig joining on any matching tuple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498259/hadoop-pig-joining-on-any-matching-tuple-values) with a slightly different approach

Comment: Is it by mistake that you have the pair `1 b` twice in your input data? If not then one obvious optimization would be to first filter out duplicates in the input relations.

Comment: The duplicate `1b` is acceptable in my data. I can try filtering them out and see if performance gets better. Thanks.

Comment: Only a small percentage of the entries were dups, so it didn't do much, but good thought.

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs contain duplicate then it's best to filter out the duplicates first because they lead to combinatorial explosion.

Another thing that you can try is to do grouping instead of a join. You get the result immediately, only not as a list of pairs:

```
mydata = LOAD '/path/to/data.tsv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (user:int, element:chararray);
A = GROUP mydata by element;
B = foreach A generate  (group, mydata.user) ;
```

`illustrate B` then gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| mydata     | user:int    | element:chararray    | 
---------------------------------------------------
|            | 1           | a                    | 
|            | 3           | a                    | 
---------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A     | group:chararray    | mydata:bag{:tuple(user:int,element:chararray)}               | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       | a                  | {(1, a), (3, a)}                                             | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| B     | org.apache.pig.builtin.totuple_group_13:tuple(group:chararray,:bag{:tuple(user:int)})                     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       | (a, {(1), (3)})                                                                                           | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So already in `B` you have all the user ids that share an element.

To get the list of pairs something like the following is necessary:

```
C = foreach B {
    X = foreach $0 generate $0.$1;
    Y = foreach $0 generate $0.$1;
    F = CROSS X, Y ;
    generate $0.group, flatten(F);
};
```

But it does not work... I'm getting:

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POProject (Name: Project[bag][1] - scope-131 Operator Key: scope-131) children: null at []]: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:338)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:378)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:298)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POCross.accumulateData(POCross.java:202)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POCross.getNextTuple(POCross.java:116)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNextDataBag(PhysicalOperator.java:385)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.processInputBag(POProject.java:590)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.PORelationToExprProject.getNextDataBag(PORelationToExprProject.java:106)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:309)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:378)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:298)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:464)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:432)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:177)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.LocalMapReduceSimulator.launchPig(LocalMapReduceSimulator.java:236)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator.getData(ExampleGenerator.java:257)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator.getData(ExampleGenerator.java:238)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.LineageTrimmingVisitor.init(LineageTrimmingVisitor.java:103)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.LineageTrimmingVisitor.<init>(LineageTrimmingVisitor.java:98)
    at org.apache.pig.pen.ExampleGenerator.getExamples(ExampleGenerator.java:166)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.getExamples(PigServer.java:1238)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processIllustrate(GruntParser.java:831)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.Illustrate(PigScriptParser.java:802)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:381)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.getNextTuple(POProject.java:476)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.processInputBag(POProject.java:592)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject.getNextDataBag(POProject.java:247)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:309)
    ... 35 more
2014-03-20 01:28:57,235 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. ExecException
```

That could be a bug in pig... I've encountered surprisingly many during this exercise.

Comment: Hmm..the end result of this seems to be just tuples of a user id to itself in E, (1,1), (2,2), and then an empty F as a result.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I didn't spend much time figuring out how to generate the  pairs for `B`, I might have a look at it later, or tomorrow, it's getting late here. Do you really need it done this way? Seems quite inefficient.

Comment: edited, I can't verify it now because my pig version 0.11 seems to have a bug in this `CROSS`: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3020

Comment: I appreciate your help. The goal really is just to find the pairs that have overlap. I can manipulate the data as I see fit. This is just my starting point.

Comment: Now I realized, I am making yet another mistake.. I'm too quick, sorry. The cross product has to be done within each group separately, then it will work...

Comment: No problem. I think this has made me realize though that I just may need a different approach in general.

Comment: I gave it one more shot but got stuck... maybe tomorrow, I would like to see the solution :)